# Better performance when function placed within conditional statement?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Bumped to this "anomaly" while bench-marking one implementation of copysign() function within round() implementation:

```
float copysign(float x, float y){
        float absx = std::fabs(x);
        /* use atan2 to distinguish -0. from 0. */
        if (y > 0.f || (y == 0.f && std::atan2(y, -1.f) > 0.f)) {
            return absx;
        } else {
            return absx * -1.0f;
        }
    }
```

By quick-benc (and another benchmark utility which measures rdtsc/val), when atan2() is moved out from condition statement it results much lower performance:

```
    float copysign(float x, float y){
        float absx = std::fabs(x);
        float atan2y = std::atan2(y, -1.f); /* use atan2 to distinguish -0. from 0. */
        if (y > 0.f || (y == 0.f && atan2y > 0.f)) {
            return absx;
        } else {
            return absx *= -1.0f;
        }
    }
```

Functions in question in Compiler Explorer [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/GrKxvEK4P) / [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/9nbG98773)

Quick C++ Benchmarks:

GCC 11.2: ([-O3 -ffast-math / -O3](https://quick-bench.com/q/9kyyvYfyLFisL3Bsnql13meVmCI))

CLANG 13.0 ([-Ofast](https://%20https://quick-bench.com/q/RRFsx1t4-1rmR87DdjMh4z-jDrs) / [-O3](https://quick-bench.com/q/-7UvHeuc2h9QGGTLww6sM54w0QY))

[Another Benchmark utility](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7170633#p7170633) results (rdtsc/val) for copysign() and round() implementation:

copysign():

```
~0.60 for "strd"  (std::copysign(), same with copysign())
~3.12 for "cs1"   (atan2() within condition statement)
~17.5 for "cs2"   (atan2() as variable in condition statement)
```

and when used in linked round() implementation:

```
~6.67 for case "strd"
~2.56 for case "cs1" 
~20.5 for case "cs2"
```

Q: What happens to atan2() when used within condition statement? Is it just inlined?

GCC has warning regarding -ffast-math usage:

> This option should never be turned on by any -O option since it can
> result in incorrect output for programs which depend on an exact
> implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions.

Q: Is this reason for lower performance when -ffast-math enabled (see linked quick-bench for GCC)?

Comment: In the first snippet `atan2` will not always be called due to short-circuit evaluation (e.g.: when `y > 0.f` is true). In the second snippet it is always called

Comment: ... and because floating point math is broken, `y` will be rarely, very rarely, exactly 0.

Comment: `atan2` is an expensive function to calculate, in the first version it is likely skipped often due to short circuiting. In the latter version it is always computed, even when eventually not required.

Comment: `y == 0.f && std::atan2(y, -1.f) > 0.f` only runs `atan2` when `y==0.f`, allowing constant-propagation for just the `-0.0` and `+0.0` cases.  And then optimization of the compare result.  You already linked the asm on godbolt; there is no call to `atan2` anywhere in `copysign_1`

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, I noticed this but thought it was inlined and therefore not seen in asm listing. So that `distinguish -0. from 0` is just a special case and therefore hardly ever faced.

Comment: @JuhaP: Well yeah, it's inlined to basically zero instructions for the case where it's known to be +-0.  But you're right, even if it was slow to run in that case, it would still run infrequently.  (That's why `-Ofast`, which is the same as `-O3 -ffast-math`, runs fast for both versions on quick-bench with clang; apparently the compiler still makes `atan2` conditional on something, just fails to constant-propagate through it, unlike for regular `-O3`.)

Comment: Note that `-ffast-math` implies `-fno-signed-zero`, so it seems your rounding functions only happen to work in that case; your copysign is broken in the general case for copying from negative zero.  If you're using C++20, might as well `std::bit_cast` to integer and use bitwise operations, at least after checking that `double` has its sign bit at the top or something.  (e.g. static_assert that `-0.0f` has the bit-pattern `0x80000000`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two major things here separate from the title question:

- Your benchmark on quick-bench looks flawed, allowing a lot of constant-propagation into your `copysign` implementations.  Check the asm.  Maybe use one global array; the compiler won't know whether something has modified it or not.  And maybe generate a random FP value (once outside the loop) to apply the sign to.
  `x=rand(); for(...) something = copysign(x, arr[i]);`
  It's weird using `copysign(x,x)` - a smart compiler could optimize that down to just `x` without doing any work, if the function correctly produces that output.
- `-ffast-math` implies `-fno-signed-zeros`, breaking your copysign implementation by not caring about signed-zero semantics when optimizing.  (`y == 0.0f` being true lets the compiler assume it actually *is* 0.0f if it wants, ignoring the possibility of -0.0f.)

---

#### Title question: atan2 inside a conditional statement.

Short circuit eval of `y == 0.f && std::atan2(y, -1.f) > 0.f` only runs `atan2` when `y==0.f`.  This is rare, so usually it doesn't happen.  (Without `-ffast-math`, it does still happen, though.  But *with* `-ffast-math`, the compiler assumes `y` is actually 0.0f if that `==0` comparison is true, allowing it to do constant-propagation through `atan2` and remove the call.)

In the fast-math case, further constant-propagation turns the `atan2() > 0.f` condition into a constant `true`, resulting in basically zero asm instructions.

You already linked the asm on godbolt; there is no call to `atan2` anywhere in `copysign_1`, all it's doing is `return (y>0.0f || y == 0.0f) ? fabs(x) : -fabs(x)`.  (Because you compiled with `-ffast-math`, which implies `-fno-signed-zeros`, so the atan2 stuff can fully optimize away, except for a strange `ja` over a `jne` instead of just a single `jae` or `jnae`.)

In `copysign_2`, GCC with `-ffast-math` does manage to pull the `float atan2y = std::atan2(y, -1.f);` into the conditional where it's used.  Clang is also able to do that; it's weird that you linked a clang benchmark but GCC asm.

---

But without `-ffast-math` (like you used on Quick-bench), clang 13 isn't allowed to do that, so it unconditionally calls `atan2` for every input.  **That's because the default is `-fmath-errno`, unfortunately.**

The call to `atan2` with an arbitrary `y` value is potentially a visible side-effect because it will set `errno` for invalid input values.  I think?  Maybe not; the `atan2` man page says it has no errors (no cases that set errno), and in the description only returning NaN if x or y is NaN.  Maybe compilers don't realize that?  But for whatever reason, using `-fno-math-errno` lets GCC and clang pull the your unconditional `atan2` inside the branch so even though it will actually call it, it only happens for the rare `y == 0.0` case (i.e. `y` being `+0.0f` or `-0.0f`)

(I thought I remembered clang not defaulting to math-errnor, only GCC, but maybe they changed or I'm mixing it up with `-fno-trapping-math`.  You should always compile with `-fno-math-errno` unless your program very strangely wants to check `errno` for `EDOM` or `ERANGE` or similar FP errors after library function calls even including `sqrt`, instead of using `fenv.h` to test the FP environment flags.)

Also `-ftrapping-math` is unfortunately on by default even though it doesn't fully work correctly.  It may try to treat it as something that may potentially run SIGFPE signal-handler code, so potentially a visible side-effect.  Or at least as maybe setting a sticky bit in the FP environment that other code could read with `fenv`.

---

BTW, this is how GCC compiled your copysign_1:

```
# gcc -O3 -ffast-math
copysign_1(float, float):
        comiss  xmm1, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]            # compare y against 0.0f
        andps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]          # clear the sign bit in x
        ja      .L3                                  # if (y>0)  return fabs(x)
        jne     .L5                                  # if (y!=0) return -fabs(x)
.L3:
        ret
.L5:
        xorps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]          # flip the sign bit of x
        ret
```

As you can see, it's broken for negative zero, `-0.0f`, clearing the sign bit of the output in that case.  Compilers of course make correct asm without `-ffast-math`, but slower and actually calling `atan2` for `-0.0` or `+0.0`.

---

BTW, despite Quick-Bench's lack of compiler option setting, it does have `-Ofast` which is currently equivalent to `-O3 -ffast-math`.  That does make everything about the same speed except for `M_STDNO`.  Not sure why that's slower; the asm involves a lot of store/reload due to the way you're using `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize`, but still allowing significant constant-propagation through your `copysign` functions.  (So they're just doing either an `andps` or `orps` to clear or set the sign bit of something.)

---

#### This is vastly over-complicated for IEEE floats

Since you're apparently using C++20, you might as well `std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(x)` and `y` to integer and use bitwise operations, at least after checking that `float` has its sign bit at the top or something. (e.g. `static_assert` that `-0.0f` has the bit-pattern `0x80000000`; you can use `std::bit_cast` in constexpr stuff like static_assert.)

You don't want any branching or multiplying, you just want `(u32x & 0x7FFFFFFFU) | (u32y & 0x80000000U)` to merge the sign bit of y with the exponent and mantissa of x.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as an answer to my questions because of this answers my questions well and is clear and instructive.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to atan2() when used within condition statement? Is it just inlined?

There was no call to `std::atan2` in assembly, hence we know that it must have been expanded inline (it could have been also eliminated as dead code, but we can deduce that's not the case).

With `-ffast-math` enabled, `y > 0.f || (y == 0.f && std::atan2(y, -1.f) > 0.f)` was essentially compiled down to `y >= 0` because the compiler didn't care to consider the difference between -0 and +0. This is an example of *"can result in incorrect output"*. If you want to treat -0 as per IEEE/ISO, the don't use `-ffast-math`.

Comment: With `-ffast-math` implying `-fno-signed-zero` (and no NaNs), it's actually equivalent to `y >= 0.0f`, not `y != 0`.  It's `x` that has `fabs` applies to it; `y` is still possibly negative.  But yeah, more or less this.  GCC `-ffast-math` compiles to a weird `ja` over a `jne` instead of a single `jae do_ret` or `jnae do_xor`, maybe as some vestige of the separate checks and possible NaN semantics no being optimized away, but equivalent to `y >= 0` anyway.

Comment: I'll recon this as useful answer. (+1)